# Android Studio version

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

I just updated Android Studio Arctic Fox and I noticed that there are different versions:

**Android Studio arctic fox**

**Android Studio Electric Eel Canary**

**Android Studio Dolphin**

**Android Studio Bumblebee**

I’m a little lost.
so I’d like to know if:

*1-their installations are independent of other*

*2-What are the differences between each of them and their usefulness ( when used one versus another ).*

*3-also if there is a better  ( forward ) than another ?*

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Differences

To answer your latter two questions first, instead of using version numbers, they are just version names. They are ordered alphabetically.

So sequentially:

- Android Studio arctic fox
- Android Studio Bumblebee
- Android Studio Chipmunk
- Android Studio Dolphin
- Android Studio Electric Eel (Canary)

The difference: newer versions have the newest features and security updates. They are otherwise the same and serve the same purpose.

The *canary* version represent a version in active development, usually released early and are prone to bugs and crashes.

The current stable release, as of this writing, is Android Studio Chipmunk.

### Are the installations independent of one another?

Not necessarily. As newer versions are released, they are installed on top of the older version. However, if you install a beta or canary version, they are usually installed independently alongside other installations.